# Objects in other namespace not found without include, files otherwise identical

Tags: c++, include, llvm, objective-c++

I have two functionally identical header files, one of which produces errors for no discernible reason. I must have done something wrong in creating the new (broken) file, but I can't figure out what.

My IDE is Xcode. The project is compiled for Objective C++ using Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1, but the section of code in question is all pure C++, no Objective C.

Here's some code:

## NamespaceA.Common.h

```
#include "../NamespaceB/Common.h"

#include "WorkingClass.h"
#include "BrokenClass.h"

...
```

## ../NamespaceB/Common.h

```
#ifndef NamespaceBCommon
#define NamespaceBCommon

namespace NamespaceB
{
    ...
}

...
#include "Superclass.h"
...
```

## WorkingClass.h

```
#ifndef NamespaceA_WorkingClass
#define NamespaceA_WorkingClass

namespace NamespaceA
{
    class WorkingClass : public NamespaceB::Superclass
    {
    public:

        WorkingClass();
        ~WorkingClass();
    };
}

#endif
```

## BrokenClass.h

```
#ifndef NamespaceA_BrokenClass
#define NamespaceA_BrokenClass

// If I don't have this line I get errors. Why??                   !!!!!
// This file is exactly identical to WorkingClass.h 
// as far as I can tell!
//#include NamespaceA.Common.h

namespace NamespaceA
{            
    // Parse Issue: Expected class name                            !!!!!
    // Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'NamespaceB'
    class BrokenClass : public NamespaceB::Superclass
    {
    public:

        BrokenClass();
        ~BrokenClass();
    };
}

#endif
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is `NamespaceB` being defined? Is the file that it is defined in being included by BrokenClass.h?

Comment: Why not post the other header files, just for completeness? As is we can't attempt to reproduce.

Comment: The code here is simplified, but it conveys all the necessary information other than that `NamespaceB` is defined in `../NamespaceB/Common.h` which you can see is included by `NamespaceA.Common.h`.

Comment: I updated the question to add a bit of `../NamespaceB/Common.h` but to me it seems evident that the problem is in the way BrokenClass was added to the project since the file is functionally identical to WorkingClass, in the same folder, both added to the same project, but only one emits errors.

Comment: Make a copy of the project, then start removing the things from places where you used "..." until either it works or you have a small complete example to ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. `WorkingClass.cpp` was including `NamespaceA.Common.h` and not including its own header file, rather than including the common file in the header and then including its own header file in the cpp.

I managed to miss the `#include` in `WorkingClass.cpp` because I just assumed it was only including `WorkingClass.h` and not `NamespaceA.Common.h`.

So in short:

## WorkingClass.h

```
// Class goes here
// No includes
```

## WorkingClass.cpp

```
// Notice it does not include WorkingClass.h for whatever reason
#include "NamespaceA.Common.h"
```

## NamespaceA.Common.h

```
#include "../NamespaceB/Common.h"

#include "WorkingClass.h"
#include "BrokenClass.h"
#include "EveryOtherClass.h" ...
```

## BrokenClass.h

```
// Class goes here
// No includes
```

## BrokenClass.cpp

```
#include "BrokenClass.h"
// Oh no! Where's NamespaceA.Common.h?
```

I'm not a big fan of this include scheme, but I'll live with it since it's a large project that I don't want to make sweeping changes to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all of the files that include namespaces and classes that you reference in your code. So, because you reference `NamespaceB::Superclass` in your `BrokenClass.h`, you need to be sure to include the file that declares that. In this case, including `NamespaceA.Common.h` (hopefully) solves this problem, because it includes the file where `NamespaceB` is included.

As for why you don't have to include `NamespaceA.Common.h` in your WorkingClass.h, I suspect it's because you just happen to have `../NamespaceB/Common.h` included somewhere else.

Comment: Neither `WorkingClass.h` nor `BrokenClass.h` have any `#include`s at all. `BrokenClass.h` will compile just fine when I uncomment the `#include`, but what I want to know is why `WorkingClass.h` is able to compile without it.

Comment: @TimR. Is something else including `NamespaceB/Common.h` anywhere, outside of the code that you're showing us? I've made a working example at https://gist.github.com/3956598 and I get errors in both WorkingClass and BrokenClass.

Comment: Thanks Xymostech, you're right. My answer to my question solves my problem, this project uses a really weird (to me at least) include scheme where every .cpp file includes the `NamespaceA.Common.h` file which includes every header in NamespaceA in addition to the `NamespaceB/Common.h` file.

Comment: @TimR. I'd guess recommend against that scheme... Although I'm not sure what the "best" way to include things is, I usually use a scheme where .cpp files only include their header files (and maybe some others to solve recursive inclusion), and in header files you include everything you have references to. That way, you don't end up with problems like these. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's the scheme I'm familiar with, which is why I was thrown off by the common file being included in the cpp file rather than just including its own header file. Unfortunately this is a really huge project that I don't want to make huge structural changes to, so this way will have to stay.